# Python - Regex find all matches in string and replace

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem on replacing string using regex, seem I can't get it to work

```
string = "<font x=''>test</font> <font y=''>test2</font> <font z=''>test3</font>"
if re.search("(<font .*?>)", string, re.IGNORECASE):
    r = re.compile(r"<font (?P<name>.*?)>.*?</font>", re.IGNORECASE)
    string = r.sub(r'', string)
```

For some reason all the regex deletes the entire string `''`. It should return as `test test2 test3`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Copied wrong code from notepad. Sorry

Comment: You can directly use `re.findall` and do this in one step

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is,

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "<font x=''>test</font> <font y=''>test2</font> <font z=''>test3</font>"
>>> if re.search("(<font .*?>)", string, re.IGNORECASE):
...     r = re.compile(r"</?font.*?>", re.IGNORECASE)
...     string = r.sub(r'', string)
... 
>>> string
'test test2 test3'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fT1kK4/1)

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `</?font.*?>` This regex would match all the opening and closing font tags. By adding `?` after the `/` will make the previous character that is `/` as optional.
- `.*?` Will do a shortest possible match. `?` after the `*` would force the regex engine to do a shortest possible match because `*` is greedy by default. It could consume so many chars as much as possible.
- `>` Matches the `>` symbol literally.
- `re.IGNORECASE` is called case-insensitive modifier.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain to me the `r = re.compile(r"</?font.*?>", re.IGNORECASE)` part please?

Comment: So this does multiple searches right? With serchall it does one  search. I am using searchall but at the same time I want to replace all whilst still getting the searchall results all in 1 time without loops.

Comment: pls ask it as new question.

Comment: regex101.com link is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
>([^<]*)<\/
```

you can use it as

```
y="<font x=''>test</font> <font y=''>test2</font> <font z=''>test3</font>"
x=re.findall(r"(?<=>)([^<]*)(?=<\/)",y) 
str=" ".join(x)
print str
```

See demo

http://regex101.com/r/xT7yD8/6